# Get final score of a user in course in Blackboard using java

Tags: java, web-services, blackboard

I want to retrieve the final score of a blackboard user in a course. 
When I go to the full grade center on course page, there is a column named "Running total" that reflects whether a user has passed that course along with the percentage he scored.

But how can I retrieve this column value in my java code through blackboard API?

Can anyone provide me a sample code .

Thanks.

Comment: Can anyone help me? I am stuck into this for a long time.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the web services?  If so, first make sure the column is set as "External Grade: yes" in the grade center.

When you pull data using the web services, check out

```
blackboard.ws.gradebook.GradebookWSImpl().getGradebookColumns()
```

For the column filter,

```
setFilterType(GET_COLUMN_BY_EXTERNAL_GRADE_FLAG)
```

Once you have the Column ID, you can pull the grades.

Make sure you use

```
blackboard.ws.gradebook.ScoreVO().getSchemaGradeValue()
```

so it gives you the same grade that is displayed in the Grade Center (letter, number, etc)

If this is not enough, I can provide a step-by-step outline of how we get grades for a single course, starting with Course ID (eg: "ART-101") and ending with a data set.

Comment: That will be a great help. Please post the answer.